# Sending SMS, image and video from imessage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

With imessage, is there any API or service provided by Apple that can be used to send SMS, image & video from within an app?

Comment: SMS only, not images or videos. Look into [MFMessageComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 4):

No you can't directly use iMessage, you can use the [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) to send a SMS. 
If the system then detects if the other user supports iMessage the SMS will be send via iMessage.

You can't force a message to send via iMessages.

Also there is no support for sending images or videos in a message via the [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html). Because [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)only support SMS which does not support images or videos.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MessageUI` framework and use

`MFMessageComposerDelegate` for SMS and

`MFMailCoposerDelegate` for email.

all it's provided by apple

Answer (score 0):

Use `MFMessageComposeViewController` to send sms from app